# Display large datasets using a vaadin8 grid - in any browser

Tags: cross-browser, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

I'm working on an app which will make heavy use Vaadin 8's Grid. I need to allow the user to scroll through/filter/sort millions of rows quickly.

The grid I have built here as a prototype works well using lazy loading, as long as the amount of data is somewhat small. Above a certain number of records, a well-known bug shows up:

https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/6290

The behaviour can be tested on Vaadin's very own demo site:

https://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/grids-and-trees/grid/large-dataset

Open the link in Internet Explorer or Edge and see for yourself. I used IE 11.98.16299.0:

[image: Vaadin 8 Grid in IE 11]

Short: IE does not show more than 40k entries, Firefox fails at 200k.

First entry in the issue log 2015, last entry October 2017. The vaadin guys say that they won't fix it in 8.x, I should wait for 10 or pay for a consultant.

Does anyone have a workaround in place for this?

*Sidenote:*

There's a reason that I didn't provide any own code snippet. The thing we're building here is based on existing code my company wrote using the [ULC](https://ulc.canoo.com/developerzone/index.html) framework. There's no static table, no static field list, everything is dynamic and hence pretty difficult to paste here - because snippets alone don't make any sense. Think of the project as "generic database browser".

Comment: Are you using some database to store this data?

Comment: Sure, it's all inside oracle. We're using a custom data provider.

Comment: What you should do is use lazy loading, but it depends how quick u want scrolling to be.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I mentioned this. We're using that already. I edited the question.

Comment: Could you please attach code with lazy loading?

Comment: @avix I updated the question - there's a reason why I didn't post code ;-) The sample on vaadin's site can be used to reproduce the issue.

Comment: This sample doesn't actually use lazy loading.